# WebSocket connection to failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403

Tags: wordpress, http, ssl, https

I updated my site `Http` to `Https`. but it's showing the WebSocket connection error

```
"WebSocket connection to 'wss://public-api.wordpress.com/pinghub/wpcom/me/newest-note-data' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case disabling temporary the JetPack plugin solved the problem.
It's a temporary fix but I needed it in order to clean the field for another bug I was facing.